# How to retrieve today's mindful minutes from HealthKit?

Tags: swift, healthkit

I'm trying to get today's mindful minutes from HealthKit, but I always get 44280 instead of 3 like in the health app, I've written this function:

```
func getDailyMindfulnessTime(completion: @escaping (TimeInterval) -> Void) {

            let sampleType = HKSampleType.categoryType(forIdentifier: .mindfulSession)!
            let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: HKSampleSortIdentifierEndDate, ascending: false)
            let startDate = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date())
            let endDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: startDate)
            let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startDate, end: endDate, options: .strictStartDate)

            let query = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: sampleType, predicate: predicate, limit: HKObjectQueryNoLimit, sortDescriptors: [sortDescriptor]) { (_, results, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(" HealthKit returned error while trying to query today's mindful sessions. The error was: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
                }
                var totalTime = TimeInterval()
                if let results = results {
                    for result in results {
                        totalTime = result.endDate.timeIntervalSince(startDate)
                        completion(totalTime)
                    }
                } else {
                    completion(0)
                }
            }
            healthStore.execute(query)

        }

}
```

What should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are adding up the time, you use this code:

```swift
if let results = results {
    for result in results {
        totalTime = result.endDate.timeIntervalSince(startDate)
        completion(totalTime)
    }
} else {
    completion(0)
}
```

However, it's not doing what you think. There are two main problems with it:

1. Instead of getting the length of the session, you're getting the time from the end of the session since the beginning of the day. To fix this, use `totalTime = result.endDate.timeIntervalSince(result.startDate)`
2. The other problem I see is that you're calling `completion` *with the length of every session, **not the total time***. This may be what you want, but if it isn't, change the inside of your query to this:

```swift
if error != nil {
    print(" HealthKit returned error while trying to query today's mindful sessions. The error was: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
}
if let results = results {
    var totalTime = TimeInterval()
    for result in results {
        totalTime += result.endDate.timeIntervalSince(result.startDate)
    }
    completion(totalTime)
} else {
    completion(0)
}
```

This sums all the sessions before calling the completion handler.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I’m trying to get and sum only the sessions in the last 24 hours

Comment: This does just get the current day. That part is managed by the predicate that you declared earlier.